# Materialize Prebuild Themes are not applying

Tags: css, angular, materialize

I have got a problem with Materialize Themes.
I tried  to apply themes in various ways and it does not work.
I installed it by npm, added to angular cli.
I added theme to style in angular.json,  imported to styles.css...
And it still does not work. - is not applying to elements:
[image]

My Cli console:
[image]

What have I done already?
In angular.json I added css files.

```
"styles": [
              "./node_modules/@angular/material/prebuilt-themes/deeppurple-amber.css",
              "./node_modules/@angular/material/prebuilt-themes/purple-green.css",
              "src/styles.css"
            ]
```

In styles.css I added following import: `@import "~@angular/material/prebuilt-themes/purple-green.css";`

3 links added in index.html

```
  <link href="https://fonts.googleapis.com/css?family=Roboto:300,400,500" rel="stylesheet">
  <link href="https://fonts.googleapis.com/icon?family=Material+Icons" rel="stylesheet">
  <link rel="stylesheet" href="lib/@angular/material/core/theming/prebuilt/deeppurple-amber.css">
```

Answer (score 0):

put inside of your src/styles.css

```
@import '@angular/material/prebuilt-themes/deeppurple-amber.css';
```